# SCORE isn't included on post

Tags: android, facebook

First of all, this is my first app and I am really having a hard time with it. So please bare with my codes for it might not be pleasing to your eyes :( I am trying to post a score, the top score, on any social networking sites especially facebook. But, on the codes below, it ONLY opens facebook and let a player give there status. It DOESN'T post the players topscore. Any help will be highly appreciated.

P.S. I've already read the Open Graph and had a hard time understanding it. Til now. Be nice :D TIA :)

```js
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My new top score is "+ ta.getText() + "!!!"); // this should appear to in the post. But IT DOESN'T !
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Score");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No application installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: you must use facebook sdk

Comment: Make use of `FacebookDialog`. It makes the cardView of the post (like the ones you see on Facebook).

Comment: Can you give me a sample? A working code will help :)